# How to Search value showing wrong index to update and delete in SQLite?

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, crud

**Search Function**

```
mSearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.d("data", charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence2, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                String select = "SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE name LIKE '"+charSequence2+"%'";
                Cursor cursor = mSQLiteHelper.getData(select);

                mList.clear();
                while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                    String name = cursor.getString(1);
                    String phone = cursor.getString(2);
                    mList.add(new Model(id,name,phone));
                }

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

**Update: This is LongClickListener where I tap to updated and delete my inserted data**

```
 mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                //Alert dialog to display options of update and delete

                final CharSequence [] items = {"Update","Delete","Call"};

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordListActivity.this);

                dialog.setTitle("Choose an Action");

                dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        if(i == 0){
                            //update
                            Cursor c = mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM RECORD");

                            ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            while(c.moveToNext() ){
                                arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                            }
                            //Show update Dialog
                            showDialogUpdate(RecordListActivity.this,arrID.get(position));
                        }
                        if(i==1){
                                //delete
                            Cursor c = mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM RECORD");
                            ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                            while(c.moveToNext()){
                                arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                            }
                            showDialogDelete(arrID.get(position));
                        }

                                //Call try
                        if(i==2){

                            TextView tvPhone = view.findViewById(R.id.textphone);
                            String phone = tvPhone.getText().toString();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
                            getBaseContext().startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

> Model: This is the Model

```
public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
```

> DataBase

```
public void updateData(String name, String phone, int id){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //Query to update record

        String sql = "UPDATE RECORD SET name=? , phone=? WHERE id=?";

        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);



        statement.bindString(1,name);
        statement.bindString(2,phone);
        statement.bindDouble(3,(double)id);


        statement.execute();
        database.close();

    }

    //Delete Data

    public void deleteData(int id){

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //query to delete record using id
        String sql = "DELETE FROM RECORD WHERE id=?";

        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindDouble(1,(double)id);

        statement.execute();
        database.close();

    }

    //Getting Data

    public Cursor getData(String sql){

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
            return database.rawQuery(sql,null);

    }
```

> Dialog

```
//DeleteDialog
    private void showDialogDelete(final int idRecord) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogDelete =new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordListActivity.this);
        dialogDelete.setTitle("Warning!!");
        dialogDelete.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
        dialogDelete.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                try{
                    mSQLiteHelper.deleteData(idRecord);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (Exception error){
                    Log.e("Delete error",error.getMessage());
                }


            }
        });

        dialogDelete.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();

            }
        });

        dialogDelete.show();
    }


                //UpdateDialog
    private void showDialogUpdate(Activity activity, int position){

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Update");

       final EditText updateNameId = dialog.findViewById(R.id.updateNameId);
       final EditText updatePhoneId = dialog.findViewById(R.id.updatePhoneId);
       final Button updatebuttonId = dialog.findViewById(R.id.updatebuttonId);

        //get Data Row Clicked  from SQLite

        Cursor cursor  = mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE id="+position);
        mList.clear();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            updateNameId.setText(name);
            String phone = cursor.getString(2);
            updatePhoneId.setText(phone);
            mList.add(new Model(id,name,phone));

        }


        //set width of dialog
        int width = (int)(activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.95);
        //set height of dialog
        int height = (int)(activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.7);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width,height);
        dialog.show();



        updatebuttonId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try{

                    mSQLiteHelper.updateData(
                            updateNameId.getText().toString().trim(),
                            updatePhoneId.getText().toString().trim(),
                            position);

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch(Exception error){
                    Log.e("Update error",error.getMessage());
                }
                updateRecorderList();

            }
        });

    }

    private void updateRecorderList() {

        //get all data from SQLite

        Cursor cursor = mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM RECORD");
        mList.clear();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String phone = cursor.getString(2);

            mList.add(new Model(id,name,phone));
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

**When I search any data in the search bar It shows me the searched data but when I click to update it, it shows me the first row data to update, and also when I click to delete it shows me the first row to delete, where is my wrong logic can you enlighten me? anyone**

Comment: Did I understand correctly that when you click on any cell, you go to the first one?

Comment: when I search any data, and it shows me searched row when I long-click to update or delete it deletes or updates the first row, and then it will go to the first row to update and delete @Leonid

Comment: Add please showDialogUpdate function in question

Comment: updated with the tag dialog (delete and update ) @Leonid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took the ID incorrectly, because you used a position that was always changing and cannot be correlated with the data.

You do not have to go to the database for the ID, as you already have it:

```
if (i == 0) {
   //update
   int contactId = mList.get(position).getId();
   showDialogUpdate(RecordListActivity.this, contactId);
}
if (i == 1) {
   //delete
   int contactId = mList.get(position).getId();
   showDialogDelete(contactId);
}
```

Comment: no bro this is not works, it's still the same, when I search for a specific alphabet it shows me the result in listview but when I click to update or delete it shows me the first-row value to update or delete . @Leonid

Comment: @IbnulImtiaz Please remove acceptance of the answer until the issue is resolved.

Comment: have you got any idea to do this problem to be solved?

Comment: but when I insert any data and click any specific list it updates and deletes the correct row. just with the help of searching then it goes the first row to be selected.

Comment: it works, but I have another problem to face is, how to insert one phone number at one time, like duplicate exist number won't take .

Comment: @IbnulImtiaz You must before add/update contact - check the database that there are no such records "SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE phone ='"+phoneNumber+"'";

Comment: you mean new method on database to check those value inserted or updated before ?

Comment: @IbnulImtiaz Before you start adding or updating contact, you must run the sql request that I threw above and check if it returned any contacts

Comment: If something is returned, then you must send the user an error that there is already such a phone number in the database.

Comment: Bro, are you there? I have solved the existing data insert check. but other things come to my mind that when I click to update, how can I check phone contact is already in the list so that I can not update with the same no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235944/discussion-between-ibnul-imtiaz-and-leonid).